# Excel SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) fails with merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-interop

Excel SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank) includes all cells in a merged range, regardless of whether they are blank.  I consider this to be a bug, and I desperately need a workaround.  Steps to duplicate:

(1) Create a worksheet with some text in cells A1 and B3. Now `activesheet.usedrange.cells.count` = 6 and
`activesheet.usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).cells.count` = 4
These values are as expected.

(2) Now merge cells A1:A2, and
`activesheet.usedrange.cells.count` = 6 and
`activesheet.usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).cells.count` = 5
Both A1 and A2 are now considered blank.

I need to find a way to select just cells A3, B1, and B2 in this case.  I'm actually doing this using .NET Excel Interop, so I do not want to have to actually retrieve the cell value as a part of the test, since this is a huge performance penalty in Excel Interop; so I'm restricted to an internal cell selection function such as SpecialCells.

Comment: The only way I can see to identify the problem ranges would be to test the intersection of blanks and non-blanks and calculate the overlap from that. I can't belileve that would be quicker than loading all the cell values into an array and processing that.

Comment: Is having merged cells unavoidable? Can you use Range("A1:A2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection instead?

Comment: Alternatively, unmerge the cells, do your stuff, then merge again.

Comment: The merging is complex and based on data in large worksheets - definitely not convenient to unmerge/remerge after the fact.  I'll try "doing my stuff" in small pieces before any merging calculations, rather than all at once at the end, and hope it's not a big performance hit.  Thanks.

Comment: Not really happy with this approach, but depending on how big your range is, you can loop through each cell of your range and determine if it is part of a `.MergeArea`.  You can use `Cells(r,c).MergeArea.Cells.Count` to determine how many cells are in the current merged area and then store `Cells(r,c).MergeArea.Address`  in an array to make sure you are not counting the merged area more than once.  At least you wouldn't have to change any of your existing merging code and you can process everything after-the-fact

Comment: I think with that merge A2 and A3 are the blanks - merged cells are defined by their top-left cell.

Comment: I had considered that, too, @Michael, but it's messy.  Another thing I tried was to chain a range selection using xlCellTypeBlanks to a range selected with xlCellTypeVisible, but apparently you can't chain the ranges like that.  Also, xlCellTypeVisible includes all of the merged cells, so that wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by selecting smaller ranges at various places in the code, usually just before doing any cell merging.  I consider this to be a workaround, not really a solution.  Thanks to those who commented - you helped inspire this workaround.